# Ruby 2.3.0: assigning to nil as Hash does not raise NoMethodError

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.3

I've just noticed a very puzzling change in behaviour between Ruby 2.2.4 and Ruby 2.3.0: trying to use `[]` on nil in an assignment does not raise a `NoMethodError` anymore.

Ruby 2.2.4:

```
box:~ jfoeh$ irb
2.2.4 :001 > a = nil
 => nil 
2.2.4 :002 > a[:b] = 1
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass
    from (irb):2
from /Users/jfoeh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

In contrast Ruby 2.3.0:

```
box:~ jfoeh$ irb
2.3.0 :001 > a = nil
 => nil 
2.3.0 :002 > a[:b] = 1
 => nil
```

Is that behaviour expected, or is this a regression of sorts?

We originally noticed this when we found such an assignment seemingly swallowing exceptions in 2.3:

```
2.3.0 :001 > require 'date'
 => true 
2.3.0 :002 > a = nil
 => nil 
2.3.0 :003 > a[:b] = Date.parse(nil)
 => nil
```

whereas Ruby 2.2 would execute the right-hand side first and raise a `TypeError` as one would expect.

Comment: Interesting... I can't find anything in the documentation of ruby 2.3 NilClass. This behavior of nil doesn't feel right, I agree with you. Have you tried submitting an issue to https://github.com/ruby/ruby ?

Comment: @Caillou I haven't; the project does not seem to have the issue tracker enabled on GH?

Comment: I tried 2.3.0 and 2.3.1 and it looks correct in 2.3.1.

Comment: @Ursus interesting, thanks! That points towards 'bug'…

Comment: @TomLord I've searched high and low and came up empty. If you happen to have an answered question handy, feel free to mark as duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

This was a bug introduced in ruby version `2.3.0`. It has since been fixed, as of version `2.3.1`.

[Here](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11976) is the original issue that was raised, on ruby-lang.org, and [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/c79402c4f0e40a3ebebda9761e47ff1b3d12ed53) is the commit which resolves the issue.